# Javascript div width countdown

Tags: javascript, math, timer, countdown

I'm trying to visualize a countdown via a div's width. This could be used for something like a banner system showing when the next banner will slide in, or for a notification system showing how long the notification will be visible.

So in my example below, I have the `.outer` div emptied after 5 seconds, but the `.timer` div's width is not reaching `width: 0%;` at the same time as the `setTimeout()` kicks in.

The variable `len` would represent how long the banner or notification would be shown for.

The calculation in the variable `offset` is what is throwing me off (I think), I cannot seem to get the calculation correct. I would like it to be dynamic, meaning, no matter what `len` is and what the width of the outer/parent div is, it will always take `len` time to reach `width: 0%;`.

I hope my explanation makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const len = 5000;
let outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

let timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
let timerWidth = timer.offsetWidth;
let offset = len / timerWidth;
let init = 100;

let interval = setInterval(() => {
   init = init - offset;
   timer.style.width = init + '%';
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
   outer.innerHTML = '';
   clearInterval(interval);
}, len);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 100px 10px 10px;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid slategray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.timer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="timer"></div>
  <p>Some Message Here!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using `%` units, so why don't you just calc how much time has passed since the start of the animation instead of trying to maintain your own counter (`init`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with the code:

1. `interval` doesn't start as soon as the page is loaded so the CSS is late in transition.
2. `offset` was wrong indeed.

Here's how I fixed it:

```js
let toElapse = 3000; // modify as you like
let tick = 1000; //if you modify this don't forget to replicate 
                 //in CSS transition prop
let countDownEl = document.querySelector('#countdown');
let outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
let timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
let init = 100;
// we calculate the offset based on the tick and time to elapse
let offset = init / (toElapse/tick); 
countDownEl.innerHTML = init;

setTimeout(()=>{
  // we need to start the first CSS transition ASAP so it is not late.
  init = init - offset;
  timer.style.width = init.toFixed(2) + '%';
},0)

let interval = setInterval(() => {
  // the same interval.
  countDownEl.innerHTML = init;
  init = init - offset;
  timer.style.width = init.toFixed(2) + '%';
}, tick);

setTimeout(() => {
   // the same clearance timeout
   outer.innerHTML = '';
   clearInterval(interval);
}, toElapse);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 100px 10px 10px;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid slategray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.timer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="timer"></div><span id="countdown"></span>
  <p>Some Message Here!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use percentage in width you don't need to know the width of your box.
you just need to substract and add on offset to timeout.

```
const len = 5000;
let outer = document.querySelector('.outer');

let timer = document.querySelector('.timer');
let timerWidth = timer.offsetWidth;
let offset = 100 * 1000 / 5000;


let interval = setInterval(() => {
init = init - 20;
timer.style.width = init + '%';
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
outer.innerHTML = '';
clearInterval(interval);
}, len + 1000);
```